# Generality of Approximation for NP Hard Problems

Tags: approximation, np-complete

I've been struggling with this question for more than a week. What is the most general approximation result that can be achieved for an NP-hard problem?

1. Approximation Algorithm
2. Approximation Scheme
3. Fully Polynomial-time Approximation Scheme
4. Polynomial-time Approximation Scheme

I can't tell if I'm the only one who doesn't understand that 'most general' means.

Comment: I think this is just a poorly phrased question. "General" could mean, "most generally useful" or "most generally applicable", it could also mean "if A is a special case of B, then B is more general than A"... voting to close

Comment: I'm inclined to think it's a question of which is a special case of which, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Well anyways, the ordering is definitely Algorithm < Approximation Scheme < Polynomial-time approximation Scheme < Fully Polynomial-time Approximation Scheme

Comment: That's helpful. Thank you.